# Align item in bootstrap navbar

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

I'm absolutly stacked while trying to align item in bootstrap navbar vertically on both desctop and mobile view.
Does anybody can explain how to di it?

I need to align avatar and name to right side on desctop and mobile and centerd vertially in navbar.
Here the HTML code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#main-nav">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand logo" href="#"><b>Super</b> logo</a>
        </div>
      <div class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <ul class="unstyled">
                <li>
                    <a href="/profile">
                        <img class="img-rounded" src="http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-c-150-150-9.jpg" alt="">
                        <span class="hidden-xs">User name</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
      <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="main-nav">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav visible-xs">
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-tachometer"></i> menu 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-wrench"></i> menu 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i> menu 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
      </div></nav>
```

and CSS

```
.navbar-toggle {
        position: absolute;
        left: 10px;
    }
.logo {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 15px 0;
    text-align: center;
    height: 20px;
}
.img-rounded {
    height: 35px;
    width: 35px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
.unstyled li {
      list-style: none;
}
.unstyled a {
      text-decoration: none;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    .logo {
        width: 150px;
    }
}
```

Here is a wrong eximple. 
http://www.bootply.com/zh0J2u4KUU

Comment: Check `ul` on bootstrap. CSS on that seems to be set and is removing the margins on top and bottom.

Comment: @David, thanks, but unfortunatly standart bootsrap `ul` and `li` classes not affected to this. I try to modify it and nothing changes.

Answer (score 0):

updated use this

```
@media (max-width: 767px)
{
ol, ul{margin-top:6px; margin-right:302px;
}


<ul class="unstyled pull-right">
 <li>
 *******
 </li>
 </ul>
```

change the logo class to pull-right!

[image: updated as like this]

Comment: simple ... say which place above the super logo or below the super logo or next to super logo ? . i will fix it now

Comment: thanks for unswer. i changed the code. on desktop it is ok, but on mobile not. here the [example](http://www.bootply.com/S4eVS7kbhJ)

Comment: and in the firs example you proposed there is margin 30px under image and not above image. so image not centered in navbar

Comment: i want this result, but as you can see top and bottom margin are not the same [image](http://imgur.com/NejdZWm)